# gulp error - _.flattenDeep is not a function when using gulp.watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sass, gulp

Why do I get `TypeError: _.flattenDeep is not a function` when I run a watch task

This is my gulpfile.js :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');



gulp.task('css', function(){
    gulp.src('public/sass2/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(autoprefixer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public/css'))
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('public/sass2/**/*.scss', ['css']);
});
```

I'm always getting this error when using the watch task, how do I get passed it?

Comment: I fixed my problem by deleting the node_modules folder and running `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

try installing lodash in the project
`npm i --save lodash`